# How to plot multiple trajectories using coordinates from a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have a data set of 2-d coordinates for each point e.g. start point and end point, in a csv. I have loaded them into a pandas data frame, but I am not sure how to visualise the coordinates into multiple trajectories?
I have looked at pymove but I need a datetime field which I do not have.
Does anyone know a way to plot these onto the same plot?

Comment: Are your trajectories time-dependent or do you just want to plot the initial and final (x,y) positions. Adding an example of your data frame would be helpful.